# I want to swap ETH to any other token on Uniswap V3. I am executing code on Remix IDE and the testnet is Goerli

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap

I am trying to swap ETH to any other coin on Remix IDE and using Uniswap V3 on Goerli Testnet. I am able to deploy the contract but the moment I am trying the swap function, it says execution reverted. The following is the error message:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: Must pass non 0 ETH amount","id":12194645375530}

I expected the result that the particular amount of token should be deposited to my account.
A solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When sending transactions on the Ethereum network, it's crucial to have enough ether for the gas fee. If you don't provide sufficient ether, the transaction will fail with the error message you mentioned.

On Ethereum network, gas fee can be paid in only ether and not any other token.